# Mock data generation for storybook

Tags: relayjs

I am trying to generate mock data using relay for storybook.
My query is

```
const QUERY_LIST = graphql`
  query modelControllerAllUsersQuery @relay_test_operation {
    allUsers {
      pageInfo {
        hasNextPage
      }
      edges {
        node {
          id
          firstName
          lastName
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

and provided RelayEnvironmentProvider as a decorator to the story. I'm trying to return some default values to my query using custom mock resolvers.

```
  const customMockResolvers = {
    ...mockResolvers,
    allUsers:() => ({
      pageInfo:{
        hasNextPage:false,
      },
      edges:[
        {
          node:{
            id       :'id',
            firstName:'fname',
            lastName :'lname',
          },
        },
      ],
    }),
  };
```

and calling it as

```
(operation) => MockPayloadGenerator.generate(operation, customMockResolvers)
```

I don't seem to be able to get the default values returned.
Currently, it is returning

```
{"allUsers":{"pageInfo":{"hasNextPage":false},"edges":[{"node":{"id":"<UserNode-mock-id-1>","firstName":"<mock-value-for-field-\"firstName\">","lastName":"<mock-value-for-field-\"lastName\">"}}]}}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the `@relay-test-operation`, the keys within your `customMockResolvers` object must match the type name of the fields, which can be different from the field names themselves.

For example, you could have the following in your schema:

```
type Foo {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}
```

and the following query:

```
query FooQuery @relay_test_operation {
  foo {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

Then the customMockResolvers object would look like this:

```
const customMockResolvers = {
  Foo: () => ({
    id: "fooId",
    name: "fooName"
  })
}
```

Notice that I'm passing in `Foo` as the key instead of `foo`.

You can check your schema and see what the the type name of `allUsers` is. I suspect it would be something like `AllUsers` or `allUsersConnection`, or something similar.

---

Also, if you're interested in creating Storybook stories for Relay components, I created a NPM package just for that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-relay-mock-environment

It doesn't require adding the `@relay-test-operation` directive to your query, and instead relies only on resolving the `String` type (which is the default for all scalar properties). You can of course still add the `@relay-test-operation` directive and also extend the resolvers by providing `customResolvers` in the config.
You can also extend the the `String` resolver as well, by providing `extendStringResolver` in the config.

Feel free to review the source code here if you want to implement something similar: https://github.com/richardguerre/use-relay-mock-environment.

Note: it's still in its early days, so some things might change, but would love some feedback!